# Can a 3rd party action invoke a chromecast app?

Tags: chromecast, actions-on-google, google-home

We are creating an action that uses a shared album service. We want to let a user say “Hey google, ask (name of service) to show our shared album on (device)” and then let the action start a casting session to a chromecast receiver that will show the family album of a user.

Which takes us back to our question. Can we invoke a "chromecast app" with a 3rd party action on a google home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at this point, no.

This has been a feature that has been teased since the Google Home was announced, but isn't yet available, with no indication when or if it might be.